# test bench of a 32x8 register file VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I wrote the assembly code for this circuit in vhdl already. I want to simulate it with a test bench.

[image]

- RegWrite: 1 bit input (clock)
- Write Register Number: 3-bit input(write addresses)
- Write Data: 32-bit input (data in)  Read
- Register Number A: 3-bit input (read addresses)
- Read Register Number B: 3-bit input (read adddresses)
- Port A:  32-bit output (data out)
- Port B: 32-bit output (data out)

I think my problem is that I don't understand what this circuit does. I chose random values to assign to the inputs, but it didn't output anything. What are good inputs to choose for this circuit?

here is my test bench file for reference:

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 

entity Reg_TB is     -- entity declaration 
end Reg_TB; 

architecture TB of Reg_TB is 
component RegisterFile_32x8
port (  RegWrite: in std_logic; 
    WriteRegNum: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    WriteData: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    ReadRegNumA: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    ReadRegNumB: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    PortA: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    PortB: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
 ); 
end component; 

signal T_RegWrite : std_logic;
signal T_WriteRegNum: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal T_WriteData: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal T_ReadRegNumA: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal T_ReadRegNumB: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal T_PortA : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal T_PortB : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin 
T_WriteRegNum <= "011";
T_WriteData <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
T_ReadRegNumA <= "001";
T_ReadRegNumB <= "100";
U_RegFile: RegisterFile_32x8 port map 
(T_RegWrite, T_WriteRegNum,    T_WriteData,T_ReadRegNumA, T_ReadRegNumB, T_PortA, T_PortB); 

-- concurrent process to offer clock signal 
process 
begin 


T_RegWrite <= '0'; 
wait for 5 ns; 
T_RegWrite <= '1'; 
wait for 5 ns; 
end process; 
process 
 begin 
wait for 12 ns; 
-- case 2 
wait for 28 ns; 
-- case 3 
wait for 2 ns; 
-- case 4 
wait for 10 ns; 
-- case 5 
wait for 20 ns; 
wait; 
 end process; 
end TB;
```

as you can see I chose

- WriteRegNum = "011"
- WriteData = "00000000000000000000000000000001"
- ReadRegNumA = "001"
- ReadRegNumB = "100"

I think that I chose bad inputs. The simulation does this:

[image]

Comment: Having a waveform display you can't read the signal names on isn't particularly helpful.  Note you can't distinguish between ReadRegNumA and ReadRegNumB.

Comment: Instead of giving up in disgust perhaps you could be a little clearer on what you don't understand?  I found several applicable questions of yours on Webby Experts that indicates we may not be articulating what you don't understand in a way the audience here gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general reading an address before it is written doesn't produce any useful results.

Your block diagram shows a 32 bit wide 8 word deep register file with two read ports and one write port with RegWrite used as a clock gated by the decode of the write address.  A stable WriteRegNum value and a rising edge on RegWrite effects a write to the address specified by WriteRegNum.

The two read ports appear completely independent.  Specifying an address on the respective ReadRegNumA or ReadRegNumB should output the contents of that register to the respective output port.

To get something useful out, you have to write to that location first, otherwise it will be the default value ((others => 'U'),) suspiciously like your waveform.

Trying writing to a location before expecting valid read data from it.  Use values that are distinguishable by register location.  Theoretically you should be preserving set up and hold time on WriteRegNum with respect to the rising edge of RegWrite.

### Example stimulus producing output:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity registerfile_32x8 is
    port (
        RegWrite:       in  std_logic;
        WriteRegNum:    in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        WriteData:      in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        ReadRegNumA:    in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        ReadRegNumB:    in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        PortA:          out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        PortB:          out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture fum of registerfile_32x8 is

    type reg_array is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal reg_file: reg_array;

    begin 
    process(RegWrite)
    begin 
        if rising_edge(RegWrite) then
            reg_file(to_integer(unsigned(WriteRegNum))) <= WriteData;
        end if;
    end process;

    PortA <= reg_file(to_integer(unsigned(ReadRegNumA)));

    PortB  <= reg_file(to_integer(unsigned(ReadRegNumB)));

end architecture;

library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 

entity reg_tb is    
end entity; 

architecture fum of reg_tb is 

component registerfile_32x8
    port (  
        RegWrite:       in  std_logic; 
        WriteRegNum:    in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        WriteData:      in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        ReadRegNumA:    in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        ReadRegNumB:    in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        PortA:          out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        PortB:          out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0)
        ); 
    end component; 

signal RegWrite:        std_logic := '1';
signal WriteRegNum:     std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
signal WriteData:       std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal ReadRegNumA:     std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
signal ReadRegNumB:     std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
signal PortA:           std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
signal PortB:           std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);

begin 

DUT: 
    registerfile_32x8 
        port map (
            RegWrite => RegWrite,
            WriteRegNum => WriteRegNum,
            WriteData  => WriteData,
            ReadRegNumA => ReadRegNumA, 
            ReadRegNumB => ReadRegNumB, 
            PortA => PortA, 
            PortB => PortB
        ); 


STIMULUS:
    process 
    begin 
    wait for 20 ns;
    RegWrite <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    RegWrite <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;
    WriteData <= x"feedface";
    WriteRegnum <= "001";
    RegWrite <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    RegWrite <= '1';
    ReadRegNumA <= "001";
    wait for 20 ns;
    WriteData <= x"deadbeef";
    WriteRegNum <= "010";
    ReadRegNumB <= "010";
    RegWrite <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    RegWrite <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;
    wait for 20 ns;
    wait;
 end process; 
end architecture;
```

> david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -a regfile_32x8.vhdl
>   david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -e reg_tb
>   david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -r reg_tb --wave=reg_tb.ghw
>   david_koontz@Macbook: open reg_tb.gtkw

[image: reg_tb showing register contents]

Essentially, the point is to have non 'U' values in a register file that's being read.  If you notice the last write to WriteRegNum = "010", PortB shows undefined output until the write occurs.

Comment: when you say "write to that location first" can you give me an example of the code? are you saying I need to assign ReadRegNumA,ReadRegNumA a value before anything else?

Comment: No. A signal with Read in it's name has nothing to do with writing.

Comment: Before reading a register has any meaning some purposeful value must be first written to it. A write entail selecting a location with WriteRegNum, and generating a 0 to 1 transition on RegWrite.  Reading on either output port is done simply by selecting the register for read using either ReadRegNumA or ReadRegNumB.  The write port and the read ports are independent.

Comment: From your waveform you're writing x"00000001" to register three (WriteRegNum = "011") over and over again.  Change either ReadRegNumA or ReadRegNumB to "011" after the first write and that value should show up on the respective read port.  The idea of a register file is to store values that may be needed for operations.  A two read port register file allows two different registers to be read and their values used as operands, say as inputs to an adder.  In general when not writing to a register RegWrite can remain high.  Bringing it low then back high causes a write.

Comment: @JimLewis -  If you were to examine the edit history of the question you'd find the VHDL implementation was for this [detailed block diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BifOR.png) and the question was solely tagged vhdl with no mention of implementation.