# nested generate statements for 32 x 8 register VHDL

Tags: vhdl

My circuit has a grid of 32 x 8 D flip flops. each row should be producing a 32 bit vectors that contain the Q values from the D-ff's - which are then sent to a 8x1 MUX. The following code is me trying to properly generate the 32 x 8 D flip flops and test if I can get a vector out of them (the 32 bit I0 vector).

the circuit I'm trying to write the implementation for can be seen in the figure posted in this question:
[test bench of a 32x8 register file VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418555/test-bench-of-a-32x8-register-file-vhdl?rq=1)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity REG is
port (
    REG_WRT     : in std_logic;
    WRT_REG_NUM : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    WRT_DATA    : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    READ_REG_A  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    READ_REG_B  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    PORT_A      : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    PORT_B      : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end REG;

architecture BEHV_32x8_REG of REG is
-- decoder component
component DCDR
    port (
        I_in    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        O_out   : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;
-- D flip flop component
component D_FF
    port (
        D_in    : in    std_logic;
        CLK     : in    std_logic;
        Q_out   : out   std_logic;
        QN_out  : out   std_logic   -- Q not
    );
end component;
-- MUX copmonent
component MUX
    port (
        S_in                            : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        I7, I6, I5, I4, I3, I2, I1, I0  : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        O_out                           : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end component;

-- internal signals used
signal I_in     : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal O_out    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal CLK_vals : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal MUXA_O_out : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal MUXB_O_out : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

-- two arrays of eight 32 bit vectors - the Q and QN outputs of all D_FFs
type reg_array is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal Q, QN: reg_array;

begin

-- decoder instance
DCDR1 : DCDR port map(I_in, O_out);

GEN_D_FF:
for ROW in 0 to 7 generate
begin
    GEN_D_FF0:
    for COL in 0 to 31 generate
    begin
        DFF_X : D_FF port map(WRT_DATA(COL), CLK_vals(ROW), Q(ROW)(COL), QN(ROW)(COL));
    end generate GEN_D_FF0;
end generate GEN_D_FF;

DCDR_AND : process(O_out, REG_WRT)
begin

    I_in <= WRT_REG_NUM;
    for I in 0 to 7 loop
        CLK_vals(I) <= O_out(I) and not REG_WRT;
    end loop;
end process DCDR_AND;

-- MUX instances
MUX_A : MUX port map(READ_REG_A, Q(7), Q(6), Q(5), Q(4), Q(3), Q(2), Q(1), Q(0), MUXA_O_out);
MUX_B : MUX port map(READ_REG_B, Q(7), Q(6), Q(5), Q(4), Q(3), Q(2), Q(1), Q(0), MUXB_O_out);

process(MUXA_O_out, MUXB_O_out)
begin

    PORT_A <= MUXA_O_out;
    PORT_B <= MUXB_O_out;

end process;

end BEHV_32x8_REG;
```

When I simulate the above code in ModelSim, I don't get any output for I0. Where is my design flawed? Am I violating any VHDL best practices? Assuming I can get this to function properly, how could I get 8 different 32-bit vectors (from each row of flip flops) to send to the MUX(s)?

I appreciate any advice I receive!

EDIT: I've updated the code to reflect advice given in the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 8 `ROW`s of 32 bit `COL`s connected to I0.  Without a reset input to the `D_FF`s at best you'd have to write to all 8 rows to get 'X's instead of 'U's.

Your MUX isn't instantiated for either read port.  If you were to implement the array value:

```
type reg_array is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal Q,QN: reg_array;
```

These would replace `I0` and `Q_out`.

From the referenced answer (you apparently just marked as useful - thanks) you could replace `I0(COL)` and `QN_out(COL)` in the `D_FF` instantiation in the inner generate statement with `Q(ROW)(COL)` and `QN(ROW)(COL)`.

Note If you're not using the Q NOT outputs of the `D_FF`s you can either not provide them as ports or not connect them (`open`).  You could also use `Q` outputs for one read `MUX` and `QN` outputs for the other read `MUX`, inverting the output of that `MUX`. With only two ports you aren't reducing the load significantly, you could just use `Q`.

For a `MUX` using signal `Q` defined as the reg_array above the MUX inputs would be `Q(0)` through `Q(7)` and the output would be either `PORT_A` or `PORT_B`. `S_in` would be connected to `READ_REG_A` or`READ_REG_B` respectively.

One thing that's not apparent from reading your VHDL design description is why there is `wait for 10 ns` in your process `DCDR_AND`?  It delays the write past the low baud of CLK (the low portion of clock).  In a zero timed model you could simply used `not CLK` instead of `CLK` (`CLK_vals(I) <= O_out(I) and not CLK`, delete the `wait for 10 ns;` line).  For a timed model resulting from synthesis, `wait` can't be synthesized. If you were to intend to synthesize, `CLK` can be used if you can count on input holdover should `WR_DATA` be clock synchronous.

And then your model has discretely instantiated `D_FF`s and uses `MUX`es for read ports.

I resisted the urge to modify your code and show it on the off chance you're doing the same class exercise.  If any of this is unclear ask in a comment on this answer and I'll add to the answer, clearly mark any corrections to it or demonstrate code if necessary.

### In response to the comment "...yet I still see UUU's for PORT_A and PORT_B"

[image: reg_tb.png]

Note that REG_WRT already shows as an inverted clock from the test bench from the previous effort, so I removed the preceding `not` in process `DCDR_AND`, otherwise using the previous effort's test bench unchanged other than matching your port names.

Also notice that the `PORT_A` and `PORT_B` outputs remain uninitialized until the address (`READ_REG_A` or `READ_REG_B`) is written to, which was the point of that particular test bench.

The idea behind writing to the flip flops (collectively 8 32 bit registers) in the middle of a clock cell (`REG_WRT`) was to avoid clock skew issues, in the case of the test bench caused by writing inputs based on delay values instead of on clock edges.

You could similarly have stimulus in a clocked process, which might require balancing clock delays to insure `WRT_DATA` and `WRT_REG_NUM` are valid at the right time.  This is also cured by using not `REG_WRT`.

If you make `REG_WRT` in the test bench an upright clock instead of inverted you can leave the `not` in process `DCDR_AND`.

There's also concurrent signal assignment statements which incidentally can go in generate statements allowing the process `DCDR_AND` to folded into the first generate statement:

```
GEN_D_FF:
    for ROW in 0 to 7 generate
    begin
GEN_D_FF0:
        for COL in 0 to 31 generate
        begin
DFF_X:  
            D_FF 
            port map(
                D_in => WRT_DATA(COL), 
                CLK => CLK_vals(ROW), 
                Q_out => Q(ROW)(COL), 
                QN_out => QN(ROW)(COL)
            );
        end generate;
DCDR_AND:
        CLK_vals(ROW) <= O_out(ROW) and REG_WRT;

    end generate;

-- DCDR_AND: 
--     process (O_out, REG_WRT)
--     begin
--
--         I_in <= WRT_REG_NUM;
--         for I in 0 to 7 loop
--             CLK_vals(I) <= O_out(I) and REG_WRT;
--         end loop;
-- end process;
```

And could also be used on the PORT_A and PORT_B assignments instead of inside the process statement.  You could also assign PORT_A and PORT_B as actuals to O_out in the two MUX instantiations, doing away with either a concurrent signal assignment or a process, for example:

```
MUX_A: 
    MUX 
        port map ( 
            S_in => READ_REG_A, 
            I7 => Q(7), 
            I6 => Q(6), 
            I5 => Q(5), 
            I4 => Q(4), 
            I3 => Q(3), 
            I2 => Q(2), 
            I1 => Q(1), 
            I0 => Q(0), 
            O_out => Port_A
        );
```

You could do this because you aren't using the read port data internally and the ports are mode `out`.

And while doing this I found that eliminating the assignment to `I_in` as above can cause all the `'U'`s on your read ports which can be cured similarly:

```
DCDR1: 
    DCDR 
    port map (
        I_in => WRT_REG_NUM, 
        O_out => O_out
    );
```

Allowing signal declarations for `I_in`, MUXA_O_out and MUXB_O_out to be eliminated:

```
-- internal signals used

-- signal I_in:        std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal O_out:       std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal CLK_vals:    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
-- signal MUXA_O_out:  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
-- signal MUXB_O_out:  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
```

I didn't have a case of always having `'U'`s on the read ports except when I had accidentally eliminated the inclusion of `WRT_REG_NUM` in `CLK_vals` as noted above.

I didn't quite finish prettifying your code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity DCDR is
    port (
        I_in:   in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        O_out:  out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of DCDR is
    signal input:   std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
begin
    input <= TO_X01Z(I_in);

    O_out <= "00000001"  when input = "000" else
             "00000010"  when input = "001" else
             "00000100"  when input = "010" else
             "00001000"  when input = "011" else
             "00010000"  when input = "100" else
             "00100000"  when input = "101" else
             "01000000"  when input = "110" else
             "10000000"  when input = "111" else
             (others => 'X');

end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity D_FF is
    port (
        D_in:     in    std_logic;
        CLK:      in    std_logic;
        Q_out:    out   std_logic;
        QN_out:   out   std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of D_FF is

    signal Q:   std_logic;

begin

FF:
    process (CLK)
    begin
        if CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1' then
            Q <= D_in;
        end if;
    end process;

    Q_out <= Q;
    QN_out <= not Q;

end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity MUX is
    port (
        S_in:                             in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        I7, I6, I5, I4, I3, I2, I1, I0:   in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        O_out:                            out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of MUX is

begin
    O_out <= I0 when S_in = "000" else
             I1 when S_in = "001" else
             I2 when S_in = "010" else
             I3 when S_in = "011" else
             I4 when S_in = "100" else
             I5 when S_in = "101" else
             I6 when S_in = "110" else
             I7 when S_in = "111" else
             (others => 'X');

end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity REG is
port (
    REG_WRT:        in  std_logic;
    WRT_REG_NUM:    in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    WRT_DATA:       in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    READ_REG_A:     in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    READ_REG_B:     in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    PORT_A:         out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    PORT_B:         out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end REG;

architecture BEHV_32x8_REG of REG is
-- decoder component
component DCDR
    port (
        I_in:       in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        O_out:      out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;
-- D flip flop component
component D_FF
    port (
        D_in:       in    std_logic;
        CLK:        in    std_logic;
        Q_out:      out   std_logic;
        QN_out:     out   std_logic   -- Q not
    );
end component;
-- MUX component
component MUX
    port (
        S_in:                            in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        I7, I6, I5, I4, I3, I2, I1, I0:  in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        O_out:                           out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end component;

-- internal signals used

-- signal I_in:        std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal O_out:       std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal CLK_vals:    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
-- signal MUXA_O_out:  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
-- signal MUXB_O_out:  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

-- two arrays of eight 32 bit vectors - the Q and QN outputs of all D_FFs

type reg_array is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal Q, QN: reg_array;

begin

-- decoder instance
DCDR1: 
    DCDR 
    port map (
        I_in => WRT_REG_NUM, 
        O_out => O_out
    );

GEN_D_FF:
    for ROW in 0 to 7 generate
    begin
GEN_D_FF0:
        for COL in 0 to 31 generate
        begin
DFF_X:  
            D_FF 
            port map(
                D_in => WRT_DATA(COL), 
                CLK => CLK_vals(ROW), 
                Q_out => Q(ROW)(COL), 
                QN_out => QN(ROW)(COL)
            );
        end generate;

        CLK_vals(ROW) <= O_out(ROW) and REG_WRT;

    end generate;

-- DCDR_AND: 
--     process (O_out, REG_WRT)
--     begin
-- 
--         I_in <= WRT_REG_NUM;
--         for I in 0 to 7 loop
--             CLK_vals(I) <= O_out(I) and REG_WRT;
--         end loop;
-- end process;

-- MUX instances
MUX_A: 
    MUX 
        port map ( 
            S_in => READ_REG_A, 
            I7 => Q(7), 
            I6 => Q(6), 
            I5 => Q(5), 
            I4 => Q(4), 
            I3 => Q(3), 
            I2 => Q(2), 
            I1 => Q(1), 
            I0 => Q(0), 
            O_out => Port_A
        );

MUX_B: 
    MUX 
        port map ( 
        S_in => READ_REG_B, 
        I7 => Q(7), 
        I6 => Q(6), 
        I5 => Q(5), 
        I4 => Q(4), 
        I3 => Q(3), 
        I2 => Q(2), 
        I1 => Q(1), 
        I0 => Q(0), 
        O_out => Port_B
        );

end architecture;

library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 

entity reg_tb is    
end entity; 

architecture fum of reg_tb is 

component REG
    port (  
        REG_WRT:        in  std_logic; 
        WRT_REG_NUM:    in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        WRT_DATA:       in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        READ_REG_A:     in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        READ_REG_B:     in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        PORT_A:         out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        PORT_B:         out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0)
        ); 
    end component; 

signal REG_WRT:         std_logic := '1';
signal WRT_REG_NUM:     std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
signal WRT_DATA:        std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal READ_REG_A:      std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
signal READ_REG_B:      std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
signal PORT_A:          std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
signal PORT_B:          std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);

begin 

DUT: 
        REG
        port map (
            REG_WRT => REG_WRT,
            WRT_REG_NUM => WRT_REG_NUM,
            WRT_DATA  => WRT_DATA,
            READ_REG_A => READ_REG_A, 
            READ_REG_B => READ_REG_B, 
            PORT_A => PORT_A, 
            PORT_B => PORT_B
        ); 


STIMULUS:
    process 
    begin 
    wait for 20 ns;
    REG_WRT <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    REG_WRT <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;
    WRT_DATA <= x"feedface";
    WRT_REG_NUM <= "001";
    REG_WRT <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    REG_WRT <= '1';
    READ_REG_A <= "001";
    wait for 20 ns;
    WRT_DATA <= x"deadbeef";
    WRT_REG_NUM <= "010";
    READ_REG_B <= "010";
    REG_WRT <= '0';
    wait for 20 ns;
    REG_WRT <= '1';
    wait for 20 ns;
    wait for 20 ns;
    wait;
 end process; 
end architecture;
```

But it runs and produces the waveform shown above.  This was done with Tristan Gingold's ghdl (ghdl-0.31) on a Mac (OS X 10.9.2) using Tony Bybell's gtkwave.  See Sourceforge pages for [ghdl-updates](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/) and [gtkwave](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you for the response! The one part that is the most unclear to me is your discussion of the timed/untimed models. I used the 'wait for 10ns' because otherwise it would loop infinitely. Also, why would I change the CLK_vals(I) definition to be 'and not CLK' when the AND gates are not inverting their REG WRITE values in the circuit design

Comment: @TylyerPlude You can add a sensitivity list to the process with CLK` and `O_out`.  There's an implied wait on sensitivity_list elements at the end of process.  With the process statement the way you have it, it will loop at 10 ns intervals no matter what, essentially causing 10 ns of uncertainty to when CLk_vals occur or go invalid.

Comment: I've modified the code to reflect changes you've suggested. I implemented a similar test file to the one you supplied in the linked question, yet I still see UUU's for PORT_A and PORT_B. My question is are there any inherent problems with this REG file as is? If not, the behavior of my flip flops is likely the problem correct?

Comment: I found the only thing stopping your model from not producing all `'U'`s was either a missing assignment to I_out or not writing to a register location being read. See the added portion of the answer.  The `not REG_WRT` also caused clock delay issues with my test bench so I removed the `not`.  Further explanation in the expanded answer.

Comment: If after all that you still have problems I'd suspect your D_FF implementation.  Also note the TO_X01Z and intermediate signal in DCDR.  The same should have been done in my MUX example, the purpose to interpret 'L' and 'H' inputs correctly, assuming MUX and DCDR could be generally used.